# Is it possible to call an Dynamics CRM action with a JSON request through a WebApi with IOrganizationService?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm

**TL;DR:**

I am calling a WebApi, the WebApi authenticates against the CRM and use the IOrganizationService, so my request is a JObject and not an Entity or EntityReference, it gives me this error:

```
Error: Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of collection 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to remove references to itself.
```

**Context:**

I built a web application in angular and I built a WebApi so I can call some custom actions in CRM:

**Angular APP | WebApi | OnPremise CRM**

So, when I call the WebApi, there is a controller that turns my request into a OrganizationRequest:

**Request for WebApi:**

```
{
    "ActionName": "custom_actionname",
    "Parameters": 
    [
        {
            "Key": "EntityInputParameter1", 
            "Value": {"@odata.type":"Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.any_entity"}
        }
    ]
}
```

I read this request on my WebApi and turn that into a request for CRM

**Request for CRM:**

```
OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest("custom_actionname");
request.Parameters["EntityInputParameter1"] = {"@odata.type":"Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.any_entity"} // This is a JObject
OrganizationResponse response = service.Execute(request);
```

When I make the request, it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of collection 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to remove references to itself.
```

If I make the request directly to the action it works, but I cannot do that due security policies.

One option could be turn the request into a valid CRM request (parsing `{"@odata.type":"Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.any_entity}` into a `Entity` type) but CRM has a lot of parsing escenarios and could be very complex.

Another option could be sending the request through web and stop using the `IOrganizationService` but I cannot change that.

I am making this question so anybody that has this error can find the "solution" because I searched a lot and nobody refers this behavior directly.

I am probably turning my InputEntityParameter into string, and I will send the JSON, so I can parse the JSON on my action, but I was looking if anybody else had this error or another approach.

Comment: what type is your `EntityInputParameter1` I suspect it is of type entity reference?

Comment: @AnkUser type is Entity

Answer (score 1):

I tested it on one of my Dev Environment with Entity as Parameter.

Below is the code I used in console application to fire Action with Entity as parameter. It ran successfully

```
var request = new OrganizationRequest("new_test");
//request.Parameters.Add("Target", xAccountReference);
request.Parameters.Add("Param2", "abc");
request.Parameters.Add("Param1", new Entity("account",Guid.Parse("2fe32f22-d01d-ea11-80fa-005056936c69")));

 Service.Execute(request);
```

Below is the Javascript code which used CRM Webapi to execute Action with Parameter. Ignore the XRM.Webapi command but interesting for you would be passing parameters in webapi.

```
var parameters = {};
parameters.Param2 = "abcd";
var param1 = {};
param1.accountid = "2fe32f22-d01d-ea11-80fa-005056936c69"; //Delete if creating new record 
param1["@odata.type"] = "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account";
parameters.Param1 = param1;

var new_testRequest = {
    Param2: parameters.Param2,
    Param1: parameters.Param1,

    getMetadata: function() {
        return {
            boundParameter: null,
            parameterTypes: {
                "Param2": {
                    "typeName": "Edm.String",
                    "structuralProperty": 1
                },
                "Param1": {
                    "typeName": "mscrm.account",
                    "structuralProperty": 5
                }
            },
            operationType: 0,
            operationName: "new_test"
        };
    }
};

Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(new_testRequest).then(
    function success(result) {
        if (result.ok) {
            //Success - No Return Data - Do Something
        }
    },
    function(error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    }
);
```

I can confirm that you are mixing Webapi and orgservice call. You can definitely call Action from Webapi of Dynamics. I just used Postman to call Action and I was successful. [Blog reference to use Postman for CRM webapi](https://rajeevpentyala.com/2019/02/13/step-by-step-postman-tool-to-test-dynamics-365-online-web-api/)

Below Body as json in Postman and I get Action to run.

```
{
    "Param1":"string test",
    "Param2":{
        "accountid":"b6b35fd0-b9c3-e311-88e2-00505693000c",
        "@odata.type":"Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.account"
            }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What I really want is to call the web api from client (a custom web api) then the custom web api calls the service.Execute, so the input parameter for the web api would be 
`"Param1": { "typeName": "mscrm.account","structuralProperty": 5}` and then, web api calls the crm action with `request.Parameters.Add("Param1", { "typeName": "mscrm.account","structuralProperty": 5})));`

Comment: I might be wrong but I think you are mixing WebAPI with OrganizationService of CRM. Orgservice is used with SDK of CRM and leveraged when service of crm is used and for Webapi as you are aware it is a http post call.

Comment: Yes! That's what I am doing because I can't call crm action directly, with an http call, I am calling a .net web api with a http call and then, calling the Orgservice with a service.Execute.

Comment: I can confirm that you are mixing Webapi and orgservice call. You can definitely call Action from Webapi of Dynamics. I just used Postman to call Action and I was successful. I have updated my answer.

Comment: {{webapiurl}} is the web api endpoint of the crm organizartion?

Comment: Yes refer to blog. Also could you please upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Ok, but I can't do this, I can't call the {{webapiurl}}new_testAction, what I need is: Call a .net WebApi (localhost/api/action), this controller should call the "new_testAction" with the service.Execute. There is a middle api between CRM and the Web Page.

Comment: No you are missing the point. You can directly reach webapi of crm with client id and secret. You do not need this middleware thing. You should google hot to use webapi for dynamics 365 with postman. You will get all the steps how to create app in active directory, how to leverage webapi capability and so on.

Comment: I can't do that due security policies. I know it will be easier but, that's why I am asking if somebody had this issue.